# Выравнивание данных

Tags: c++, оптимизация, структуры, процессор, микроархитектура

Наткнулся на термин *Выравнивание данных* в статье «[Оптимизация кода на C++ (C++11) на примере конкретной задачи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/256929/)». В той статье код оптимизируется путем изменения порядка расположения переменных в структуре.

Почему происходит оптимизация кода, только из-за изменения порядка расположения переменных?

Comment: Там же русским по белому написано: "перемещение данных «туда-сюда» стоит времени", а изменение порядка следования полей в структуре приводит к изменению ее размера.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, не всегда только от изменения размера. Конечно, зависит от процессора, но часто арифметика (в т.ч. сравнения) с естественно выровненными данными (адрес кратен размеру типа) быстрее, чем с не выровненными (даже если архитектура позволяет с ними работать).

Comment: @avp это понятно, те же SIMD-инструкции чувствительны к выравниванию данных. Просто наиболее простое и очевидное в статье - изменение размера.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Если честно, то просто не обращайте на это внимания. Такая нанооптимизация не понадобится большую часть вашей жизни. Большая часть проблем решается не перестановкой полей структуры, а вдумчивым переписыванием алгоритмов и выбором подходящих структур данных. Хотя конечно знать про это надо.

---

Итак, смотрите, в чём дело.

Память компьютера работает следующим образом. Память программы можно представить себе как большой массив байт, а адрес — индекс в этом массиве.

```
[байт 0] [байт 1] [байт 2] [байт 3] [байт 4] [байт 5] [байт 6] [байт 7]...
```

(Ну или иногда легче представлять так:

```
... [байт 7] [байт 6] [байт 5] [байт 4] [байт 3] [байт 2] [байт 1] [байт 0]
```

— вам ещё предстоит узнать про разницу между Big Endian и Little Endian.)

Байт, как минимально адресуемую единицу памяти, можно адресовать как угодно. Но обычно вы работаете с более крупными единицами. Например, это *машинное слово*: размер регистра процессора. Для 32-битной архитектуры это четырёхбайтовая структура.

Теперь, байты прекрасно организовываются в четвёрки:

```
[байт 0] [байт 1] [байт 2] [байт 3] [байт 4] [байт 5] [байт 6] [байт 7]...
[        машинное слово 0         ] [        машинное слово 1         ]...
```

Но заметьте, что в принципе байты можно бы комбинировать в машинные слова и по-другому:

```
[байт 0] [байт 1] [байт 2] [байт 3] [байт 4] [байт 5] [байт 6] [байт 7] [байт 8]...
         [          машинное слово         ] [     ещё одно машинное слово     ]...
```

— машинное слово может начинаться по любому адресу!

Так вот, большинство компьютеров устроено так, что машинные слова, скомбинированные в четвёрки верхним образом читаются быстро, а вот машинные слова второго типа (то есть, те, которые не получаются шагами по 4 от нуля) — медленно. (Хотя требования по выравниванию могут быть и сложнее, и не совпадать с кратностью машинного слова.) Хуже того, очень многие архитектуры вовсе не позволяют читать такие слова, и для того, чтобы прочитать вот такое слово:

```
[байт 0] [байт 1] [байт 2] [байт 3] [байт 4] [байт 5] [байт 6] [байт 7]...
         [          машинное слово         ]
```

приходится читать машинные слова по адресу 0 и 4

```
[байт 0] [байт 1] [байт 2] [байт 3] [байт 4] [байт 5] [байт 6] [байт 7]...
         [    нужно это машинное слово     ]
[     но приходится читать это    ] [              и это              ]
```

выбирать из них нужные байты, перетасовывать и собирать «вручную» в нужное машинное слово! Понятно, что это сложная и сравнительно дорогостоящая операция.

Поэтому компиляторы языка программирования C (да и большинства других тоже) проводят такую оптимизацию: между полями структуры вставляются незначащие байты для того, чтобы у всех полей было хорошее выравнивание.

Пример: для такой структуры:

```
struct
{
    char x; // 1 байт
    int y;  // 4 байта
    char z; // 1 байт
};
```

память выделяется так:

```
[    ] [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ]
[  x ] { потерянные байты } [             y           ] [  z ] { потерянные байты }
```

Если сама структура будет выровнена в памяти (об этом компилятор тоже заботится), то `y` будет выровнено, и доступ к нему будет быстрым (а на некоторых платформах, напомню, вообще только в этом случае возможен).

Но в этом случае наша структура занимает больше памяти, чем если бы порядок переменных был таким:

```
[    ] [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ]
[  x ] [  z ] {  потеряно } [             y           ]
```

Бóльшая структура означает бóльший расход памяти и бóльшие затраты на копирование, чтение этой структуры и тому подобное. Таким образом, переставив поля структуры, мы можем сэкономить.

---

Обратите внимание, что на самом деле универсальной оптимизации не существует. Например, для разных архитектур компьютера размер машинного слова будет отличаться. Кроме того, и размеры сколько-нибудь сложных данных могут отличаться тоже, а значит вычисленный оптимальный порядок на одной системе может оказаться *очень* неоптимальным на другой системе.

---

Дополнительное чтение по теме (на английском): http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

Comment: Для полноты картины я бы добавил что-нибудь про CPU cache , его типичный размер, разницу в 2 порядка скорости доступа к нему и RAM (и следовательно рабочий набор данных), построчный обмен с RAM и предвыборку данных.

Comment: @avp: Я в этом не силён, может быть, вы добавите отдельным ответом?

Comment: Сейчас что-то нет желания.

Comment: @avp: Очень жаль! Тогда может быть когда появится желание и свободное время...

Comment: хм.. как-то кривовато звучит фраза _...такая оптимизация: между полями структуры вставляются незначащие байты..._. Правильно я понимаю, что имеется в виду - компилятор выравнивает члены в структурах по адресам, кратным их размеру (и именно поэтому возникают "лакуны" в структурах)?

Comment: @o2gy: Выравнивает — да, по адресам, кратным размеру — ен обязательно. Например, для интеловских процессоров достаточно выравнивания на границу 4 что ли байтов для структуры любого размера (а для двухбайтных — на границу 2-х). Для каждого процессора — свои требования.

Comment: Ну я больше хотел сказать вот что - фраза "_вставляются незначащие байты_" оставляет вопросы - кем вставляются эти самые байты?

Comment: То есть, "дырки" в структурах появляются не от того, что между членами вставляются незначащие байты, а от того, что компилятор соответствующим образом разместил данные. А если бы компилятор данные не трогал, то все структуры были бы идеально плотно упакованы. Но тогда доступ к ним во многих случаях стал бы медленнее.

Comment: @o2gy: Дырки в структурах потому, что компилятор разместил между ними незначащие байты для выравнивания. И кстати, невыровненные данные многие процессоры просто отказываются обрабатывать. Почитайте: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/14/229387.aspx

Comment: Вот, так фраза звучит понятнее и логичнее.

Comment: @VladD в вашем примере размер машинного слова равен 4 байтам, почему? И может ли машинное слово быть равно 8,16,32,64 и более? И от чего это зависит?

Comment: @MaximPro: Может, конечно. У меня там наверху написано: «Для 32-битной архитектуры это четырёхбайтовая структура.» Были в истории и 16-битные, и 8-битные, и 64-битные, и, кажется, 128-битные архитектуры. Были даже недвоичные архитектуры, да.

Comment: @VladD я не про биты имел, а про байты `8,16,32,64 и более?`

Comment: @MaximPro: Ну, Intel 286 были 16-битные, там машинное слово было 2 байта. 80386 уже были 32-битными, 4 байта на слово, а некоторые Пентиумы уже вроде бы были 64-битными.

Comment: @VladD я вас понял то есть максимум всего 8 байт может составлять машинное слово?

Comment: @MaximPro: Ну, я не вижу теоретического предела. Сейчас вроде бы 128-битных архитектур нету, нор в будущем могут появиться.

Comment: @VladD а что будет если мой тип данных занимает к примеру 16 байт, а в моем процессоре размер регистра 64 бита (8 байт), получается в регистр нельзя положить мой тип данных. Что происходит в данном случае?

Comment: @MaximPro: По-разному. Например, его можно положить в _несколько_ регистров. Или передать через регистр указатель на него, и код будет работать с ним по кускам (но от вас это скроет компилятор).

Comment: @VladD выравнивание в данном случае будет кратно 16 байтам? Где можно про это почитать? А то столько вопросов

Comment: @MaximPro: Хороший вопрос! Зависит от процессора, _обычно_ выравнивание происходит на величину кратную размеру машинного слова. Так что скорее всего, да. // Где почитать, даже не знаю. Лучше спросите у avp, он разбирается :)

Comment: @VladD а хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

На самом деле, столкнуться с негативными последствиями невыравненных данных не так сложно.

Но вопрос был про члены в структурах, а по этому поводу я хотел бы дополнить, что существует интересный инструмент, обнаруживающий вот такие неоптимальности в коде.

Называется этот инструмент - *pahole* (данная утилита входит в состав пакета *dwarves*).

Приведу пример ее работы.
1) Код (сокращенный):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct B
{
    char a1; 
    int  b[2];
    char a2; 
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct B b;   // надо, чтобы "подозреваемые" структуры использовались
    return 0;
}
```

2) Компиляция с отладочной информацией: `gcc -g 1.c`
3) Запуск анализа: `pahole -R a.out`
    Ключик `-R` означает reorganize.
4) Вывод программы:

```
pahole -R a.out 
struct B {
    char                       a1;                   /*     0     1 */

    /* XXX 3 bytes hole, try to pack */

    int                        b[2];                 /*     4     8 */
    char                       a2;                   /*    12     1 */

    /* size: 16, cachelines: 1, members: 3 */
    /* sum members: 10, holes: 1, sum holes: 3 */
    /* padding: 3 */
    /* last cacheline: 16 bytes */
};
```

Видим, что в нашей структуре имеется "дырка" между a1 и массивом b. Кроме того, замечаем, что вес такой структуры - 16 байт. Попробуем переставить местами члены в структуре следующим образом:

```
struct B
{
    char a1; 
    char a2; 
    int  b[2];
};
```

Вот так будет лучше! "Дырка" все еще присутствует между a2 и массивом b, но теперь "дырка" занимает 2, а не 3 байта, а общий вес структуры снизился до 12 байт.

Comment: Только не надо забывать, что почти все ОС на самом деле выделяют память кусками, размер которых кратен странице (типично 4К).

Comment: @avp, это на самом деле очень интересный вопрос! также заслуживающий, наверное, отдельного обсуждения или развернутого ответа. память-то выделяется страницами, но менеджеры памяти (malloc, jemalloc, tcmalloc e.t.c.) обычно сразу "кушают"  большой кусок, делят его на "чанки" (по 8 байт, по 16, по 32 и т.д. ) и прикладной код уже обычно получает именно эти "чанки".

Comment: Откровенно говоря, не знаю, что тут еще можно обсуждать. Если только упомянуть, что, например, стандартный glibc `malloc(1)` на самом деле будет выделять вместо одного байта целых 16 байт на 32-bit Linux (и 32 байта на 64-бит системе).