# Получение указателя на созданную структуру на этапе компиляции

Tags: c

Требуется создать на этапе компиляции односвязный список из структур, имеющих следующий тип:

```
typedef struct word{
    struct word *previous;
    char *name;
    uint8_t flag;
    void(*xt)();
}word;
```

То есть, первая структура создается как `{0, "plus", 0, add)`, то вторая уже должна инициализироваться как `{previous, "minus", 0, sub}` , где previous - адрес созданной до этого структуры. При этом хранить адрес структуры в переменной невыгодно, т.к. на каждую структуру придётся создавать свою переменную, а количество памяти сильно ограничено. Поэтому хочется каким-то образом сохранить адрес в памяти, чтобы затем его использовать, при этом не выделяя под него дополнительную SRAM.

Попробовал сделать что-то вроде:

```
#define STRUCT {0, "+", 0, add}
word last_word = {&(STRUCT), "-", 0, sub};
```

Но компилятор, ожидаемо, ругается на эту строку, поскольку вместо STRUCT подставляется выражение, а не полученный адрес. Каким образом я могу получить доступ к памяти напрямую, чтобы занести в неё объекты?

Comment: Вы хотите безымянные глобальные переменные?

Comment: @Harry скорее переменные на этапе препроцессинга, потому что из-за ограниченности памяти мне бы хотелось, чтобы во время выполнения эти адреса хранились только в односвязном списке.

Comment: Давайте подумаем так - вы делаете односвязный список. Добавлять в него после его инициализации вы будете что-то вряд ли, тем более что это "что-то" должно идти из динамической памяти. У вас могут начаться проблемы при попытке удалений и т.п. Так не проще сэкономить и сделать **массив** этих структур? Как минимум вы экономите один указатель - как я понимаю, для вас существенно...

Comment: @Harry Я бы хотел создать примерно следующий код:
1 - у меня есть n функций, которые ничего не принимают и не возвращают, а работают с глобальными для всего проекта переменными. 
2 - после функции следует объявление новой структуры вида: ссылка на предыдущую структуру, имя, флаг, адрес функции.
При этом хотелось бы изменять порядок и количество функций, каждый раз не меняя индексы, или какие-либо другие константы.

Comment: На этапе компиляции никаких адресов быть не может. Или вы имеете в виду что-то другое, поясните.

Comment: @Cerbo адреса должны подставляться на этапе линковки, согласен, но так как переменные вне функций, то место под них должно выделяться не при входе в функцию, а перед запуском программы они уже должны где-то лежать, если я правильно всё понимаю. 
Мне нужно понять, можно ли средствами языка C создать ДО запуска программы связный список и если нет, то как это сделать с наименьшими затратами оперативной памяти, т.к. ограничение порядка 64 KByte.

Comment: @Oshnix: А где вы хотите, чтобы ваши экземпляры находились? В стеке, как локальные переменные? В куче? В глобальной памяти, как глобальные переменные?

Comment: @VladD Либо в куче, либо я могу вручную выделить под них память. Так как я работаю на микропроцессоре, то у меня есть прямой доступ к SRAM.

Comment: @Oshnix: Окей, а количество структур известно в compile-time? А вот так не покатит: http://ideone.com/5lEIG0?

Comment: @Oshnix: (это правда не в куче, зато в compile-time)

Comment: @VladD да, количество структур - известно. Только тут вопрос возникает, не будет ли на стеке под каждую переменную дополнительно память выделена? Я понимаю, что количество функций, конечно, будет достаточно небольшим, до 1024. Поэтому и спрашиваю, есть ли путь, который после запуска не оставит после себя следов. Если нет, то придётся именно так и делать.

Comment: @Oshnix: Вот сишный вариант: http://ideone.com/HMGAdt. Нет, тут в стеке не выделяется ничего, это по идее глобальные переменные. А в каком смысле «не останется следов»?

Comment: @Oshnix: Выделить структуры в compile-time в стеке или куче нельзя потому, что в этот момент ещё неизвестно, где будет этот самый стек или куча.

Comment: @VladD это скорее всего я не очень понял, как происходит для языка C процесс компиляции. Хотел просто по аналогии с assembler'ным кодом сделать прямое выделение в памяти, но прямой доступ к секциям data и text через С всё-таки недоступен. Спасибо большое за объяснение.

Answer (score 0):

Окей, если вы хотите выделить структуры во время компиляции, проще всего, наверное, будет такой код:

```
typedef struct word {
    struct word *previous;
    char *name;
    uint8_t flag;
    void(*xt)();
} word;

word w1 = { 0, "plus", 0, add };
word w2 = { &w1, "minus", 0, sub };
```

и так далее.

Это разместит данные в области для глобальных переменных. Привязка имени `w1`, `w2` не создаёт проблем по идее, т. к. привязывает имя `w1` к *самой выделенной области памяти*.

---

Если вы хотите выделить переменные в куче, вы не можете этого сделать на этапе компиляции (потому что вам нужен `malloc`). В этом случае вам нужно что-то такое:

```
typedef struct word {
    struct word *previous;
    char *name;
    uint8_t flag;
    void(*xt)();
} word;
```

```
word* root = malloc(sizeof(word));
*root = (word){ 0, "plus", 0, add };

word* prev = root;
root = malloc(sizeof(word));
*root = (word){ prev, "minus", 0, sub };

prev = root;
root = malloc(sizeof(word));
*root = (word){ prev, "times", 0, mult };

// ...
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/8oPOE9).

---

Если экономить память, то имеет смысл завести массив, как в ответе @Harry, и заменить указатель на индекс в массиве. Это будет в зависимости от размера таблицы один или два байта. Но нужно [подобрать правильный порядок полей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435733/10105), минимизирующий `sizeof(word)`.

```
typedef struct word
{
    void(*xt)();
    char *name;
    uint8_t index;
    uint8_t flag;
} word;

word words[] =
{
    { add,  "plus",  0, 0 },
    { sub,  "minus", 1, 0 },
    { mult, "times", 2, 0 },
    // ...
};

const uint8_t number_of_words = sizeof(words) / sizeof(word); // не занимает памяти
```

Имея индекс, легко переходить к предыдущему/следующему элементу.

Answer (score 0):

Если заранее известно количество структур, а с памятью напряженка - я бы делал это массивом:

```
typedef struct word{
    // struct word *previous;
    char *name;
    uint8_t flag;
    void(*xt)();
} word;

word w[] = {
    { "plus", 0, add };
    { "minus", 0, sub };
    ...
};
```

При этом тратится меньше памяти, выше скорость обращения, все операции быстрее - словом, одни выгоды :)

Если **позарез** нужен список - то чтоб не плодить имя для каждой структуры, я бы опять же работал через массив:

```
typedef struct word{
    struct word *previous;
    char *name;
    unsigned char flag;
    void(*xt)();
} word;

word w[] = {
    { 0, "plus", 0, add },
    { &w[0], "minus", 0, minus },
    { &w[1], "product", 0, prod  }
    ...
};
```

По крайней мере, не придется придумывать новое имя для каждой из... сколько вы там сказали? 1024? структур.

Comment: Если уж экономить память, то нужно сообщать структуре не указатель на предыдущую, а её индекс в массиве. При правильном порядке полей это сэкономит память.

Comment: @VladD Можно, но ТС очень хотел именно связный список через указатели - так, по крайней мере, я понял его комментарии - он хотел затем добавлять в список свои элементы.

Comment: Ну, если память ограничена, то массив с несколькими свободными слотами — тоже хорошая альтернатива. Особенно если это экономит память. В любом случае, пусть ТС выбирает из предложенных решений.

Answer (score 0):

Запросто

```
word *list = &(word) { &(word) { NULL, "plus", 0, add }, "minus", 0, sub };
```

Все.

Будучи расположенным в file scope такой список живет по правилам статических переменных (т.е. "вечно"). Будучи расположенным в block scope он живет по правилам обычных локальных переменных.

С точки зрения языка С, при расположении в file scope, все инициализаторы в данном примере являются *константами* (иначе бы код не скомпилировался вообще), т.е. значениями времени компиляции. Разумеется, с точки зрения деталей реализации, значение адресной константы может не сформироваться даже на этапе линковки, т.е. стать известным только в момент загрузки. А уж соответствует ли все это вашему "на этапе компиляции" - вам решать.