# Правильно ли я посчитал?

Tags: c, winapi, struct

Скажите правильно ли я посчитал, сколько байт нужно для этой структуры ...

```
typedef struct _WIN32_FIND_DATA {
  DWORD    dwFileAttributes;
  FILETIME ftCreationTime;
  FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
  FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
  DWORD    nFileSizeHigh;
  DWORD    nFileSizeLow;
  DWORD    dwReserved0;
  DWORD    dwReserved1;
  TCHAR    cFileName[MAX_PATH];
  TCHAR    cAlternateFileName[14];
}
```

4+((4+4)*3)+(4*4)+261+14=319 байт

Comment: Не факт, зависит от добавляемого выравнивания. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435733/10105 Воспользуйтесь лучше `sizeof`.

Comment: Кстати, разве `MAX_PATH` не 260?

Comment: И размер `TCHAR` может быть не 1.

Comment: @VladD так `MAX_PATH` вроде-бы 260 без учёта последнего "0" (конец строки), а `TCHAR` я посчитал как массив из 14 байт.

Comment: @VladD прикиньте я ошибся всего лишь на 1 :D. `sizeof` насчитал 318 байт, но я не могу понять одного, то-есть `cFileName` хранит в себе название длинной 259 и ещё символ "0"?

Comment: Ну, если у вас указана длина 260, то отводится ровно 260 символов, откуда компилятору знать, что это не массив, а именно строка? Как именно внутри представлена строка (есть ли финальный `\0` для длинных строк), надо смотреть в документации.

Comment: @VladD ну в masm'e значит будет 260 байт выделяться на строчку?

Comment: В masm'е? (о_О)

Comment: в masm тоже есть [sizeof](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-sizeof) - пользуйтесь

Comment: @mega спасибо, я уже в пред-предыдущем комментарии уже его подсчитал через sizeof :)

Comment: @VladD ну а что, я же могу резервировать на нём struct'уры )

Comment: @VladD оформите пожалуйста ваш совет с `sizeof` как ответ, я его отмечу

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: Оформил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Размер структуры зависит от многих факторов, например, от размера `TCHAR` (1 или 2 в зависимости от платформы), и [выравнивания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435733/10105), вставляемого между элементами структуры компилятором.

Поэтому лучше всего не считать вручную, а воспользоваться оператором `sizeof`.