# Зачем нужно выравнивание в памяти?

Tags: оптимизация, выравнивание, процессор

Зачем выравнивать в памяти,  например,  4 байтные int-ы,  так,  чтобы их адрес был кратен четырем? Ведь оперативная память может выдать на шину данных машинное слово,  начинающееся с любого адреса. Или все дело в кэше процессора,  в котором данные храняться построчно(например по 64 байта),  тогда выравнивание гарантирует что объект точно находиться в одной строке?

Comment: Выравнивание нужно, например, для SSE-инструкций, который не работают с невыровненными данными. Некоторые процессоры вообще не работают с невыровненными данными.

Comment: Вот по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435726/10105.

Comment: @Asem учитывая архитектуру x86/64, процессор не может просто так взять и достать с памяти 1 байт.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выравнивание данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435726/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Answer (score 1):

Цитата из Википедии:

> Выравнивание данных в оперативной памяти компьютеров — способ
>   размещения данных в памяти особым образом для ускорения доступа.
>
> Центральные процессоры в качестве основной единицы при работе с
>   памятью используют машинное слово, размер которого может быть
>   различным. Однако, размер слова всегда равен нескольким байтам (байт
>   является наименьшей единицей, в которой отсчитываются адреса). Как
>   правило, машинное слово равно {\displaystyle 2^{k}} 2^k байтам, то
>   есть состоит из одного, двух, четырёх, восьми и т. д. байтов.
>
> Некоторые модели процессоров не могут обращаться к данным в памяти,
>   нарушающим границы машинных слов. Некоторые могут обращаться, но к
>   невыровненным данным дольше, нежели к данным, находящимся внутри
>   целого «машинного слова» в памяти.