# Выравнивание полей структуры

Tags: c++, структуры, toolbar, выравнивание

Прочитал ответ на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435726/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), где говорилось о выравнивании полей структуры и загорелся идеей пересчитать размер такой структуры:

```
struct Worker
{
    char name[10];                       
    char position[10];                   
    float salary;                       

    unsigned short missedDays : 5;       
    unsigned short mDaysWithoutReas : 5; 
}
```

Итак, я представил память в виде массива и начал подсчеты.
1. Строка `name`. Она состоит из 10 байтов, но выравнивание добавляет еще 2.
`[ 0 ] [ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] [ 5 ] [ 6 ] [ 7 ] [ 8 ] [ 9 ] [   ] [   ]`
`[        word 0       ] [        word 1       ] [        word 2       ]`
Итого получается 12 байтов.
Аналогично подсчитывается следующая строка.
И теперь мы получили размер двух строк, равный `12 байтов * 2 строки = 24 байтов`.
2. `float salary`. Тип `float` занимает 4 байта, а значит одно машинное слово:
`[ 0 ] [ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ]`
`[        word 0       ]`
соответственно, мы уже получили размер `24 байтов + float = 28 байтов`.
3. Битовые поля. Т.к. в сумме они дают 10 битов, то будет зарезервировано под них 2 байта (16 бит).
В итоге у нас получилась сумма `28 байтов + 2 байта = 30 байтов`.

Но, найденный мною размер не соответствует тому, что возвращает  функция `sizeof()` для типа `Worker`. А именно на выходе я получаю не `30 байтов`, а `28 байтов`!
Почему так получается?

Comment: Вам же в вопросе по ссылке все расписали. Битовые поля, как однобайтовые, могут размещаться с любым смещением, в том числе в хвосте массива.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, благодарю за ответ. Вероятно, именно это я и не понял. Не могли бы Вы объяснить?

Comment: У меня gcc вообще ничего не выравнивает. Всё ставит как есть 10+10+4+2+2. Даже битовые поля не сливает вместе. Может не видит в этом смысл?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, а почему Вы дважды прибавляете 2 байта?

Comment: Это не я а компайлер.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, понимаю. А почему так? Там под оба битовых поля выделено всего 2 байта, а не 4 байта.

Comment: @BorisMakhlin, битовые поля вполне могут располагаться в 11-м и 12-м байтах структуры.

Comment: Перенёс битовые поля первыми и увидел их размеры. Всё правильно, смещения в структуре могут быть любыми, а размер  **всей** структуры выравнивается.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!