# Получение доступа к полям класса через сдвиг в адресе объекта класса

Tags: c++, c

Для образовательных целей хочу достучаться ко второму полю данного класса через указатель:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(char a, double b): a(a), b(b) {}
    char a;
    double b;
};
```

Делаю это следующим образом:

```
Foo *foo = new Foo('a', 2.0);
std::cout << *((double *)((char *)foo + 1)) << std::endl;
```

В ответе у меня получается мусор. Не могу понять почему. Я же вроде сдвинул указатель на один `char` и пытаюсь прочитать как `double`. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: [Выравнивание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435733/276430)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть такая штука, как [выравнивание данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435726/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). Соответственно большинство компиляторов вставят несколько неиспользуемых байт (*padding*) между `c` и `b` и упакуют эту структуру в памяти неким подобным образом:

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |10 |11 |
  ^  \---------/ \-----------------------------/
  |       ^                     ^
  |   padding                double b
  | (Пустые байты)
char c
```

Для получения таких смещений в языках C/C++ есть макрос [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof). Соответственно корректное получение адреса будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
(double *)((char *)foo + offsetof(struct Foo, b));
```

Одна из возможных реализаций макроса может раскрываться в нечто подобное<sup>*</sup>:

```
(double *)((char *)foo + (size_t)&(((struct Foo*)0)->b)));
```

Но на практике это обычно реализуется с помощью встроенных функций компилятора.

---

<sup>* не использовать в реальном коде, содержит полтора UB</sup>

Comment: "На практике" `offsetof` уже давно ни во что не раскрывается, кроме встроенной инструкции компилятора навроде `__builtin_offsetof`.

Comment: @AnT, спасибо поправил...

Comment: Только не `void*`, а `char*`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, спасибо, конечно...