# Почему процессор "не любит" невыровненные данные?

Tags: память, железо, выравнивание, процессор, микроархитектура

Сразу скажу, скорее всего мой вопрос является дубликатом [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435726/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). Но я бы его не задавал, если бы мне все было понятно.

Первое что меня интересует, это какой размер данных процессор может считывать за раз? Насколько я понимаю, процессор считывает такой размер данных, который равен размеру его машинного слова, например 32 бита. То есть даже, если процессору нужно прочитать всего лишь 8 бит информации, то он все равно прочитает 32 бита, но работать будет только с нужными ему 8-ю битами. Правильно ли я это понимаю?

Но возникает другой вопрос, многие говорят говорят что процессор очень плохо работает с данными которые расположены по адресу, *не*кратному размеру его машинного слова. То есть допустим машинное слово имеет размер 4 байта, то почему процессор не сможет прочитать данные расположенные по адресу `0x5`? Я просмотрел довольно много сайтов и статей, связанных с моим вопросом, но многие люди просто говорят, что так нельзя, а причину не называют.

Единственное, что я слышал по этому поводу, это SSE-инструкции и то что они плохо работают с такими адресами. Есть ли ещё какие-либо причины такого поведения процессора?

Comment: `0x5` адрес не такой проблемный. Для чтения 8 байт по адресу 0x1A процессор дает инструкцию прочитать блок на кеш, с кеша читает 0x0, сдвигает, скидывает в регистр, читает 0x20, сдвигает  и прибавляет к регистру - итого 7 операций.

Comment: Лучше спросите на английском SO. Здесь, вроде, нет людей, кто хорошо разбирается в теме.

Comment: есть есть, не нужно наговаривать

Comment: @KoVadim, да? А кто? У нас не так много вопросов и ответов по микроархитектуре и железу, может, я что-то и пропустил.

Comment: да, потому что подобные вопросы очень часто минусуются, как и ответы, из за того, что есть большой пласт отвечающих, которым они не нравятся.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну минусов я на подобных вопросах не замечал, их скорее просто как-то обходят стороной — видимо, мало кому интересны.

Comment: не хотят минусов

Comment: @eanmos, зачем спрашивать то, на что уже отвечали? [EnSO: Purpose of memory alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381244/purpose-of-memory-alignment/381368). Ответ правда как всегда банален, архитектура некоторых процессоров не позволяет эффективно читать за раз не выровненные данные. Хотя в вашем ответе вы полезли совсем уж в дебри железа.

Comment: @AlexKrass, ответ «архитектура большинства процессоров не позволяет эффективно читать за раз не выровненные данные» — это не ответ, а собственно исходный вопрос. Если вы прочитаете вопрос внимательно, то заметите следующие слова ТС: «многие люди просто говорят, что так нельзя, а причину не называют». Вопрос в том, **почему** процессор не может эффективно читать по невыровненным адресам.

Comment: @eanmos, вы призываете спросить на EnSO, я дал ссылку на вопрос на EnSO, внимательнее надо быть) Я вот внимательно прочитал всю ветку и даже посмотрел, а не ли уже ответов на этом самом EnSO. А ответ как ответ, вы не делаете возможным читать такие данные ради удешевления и упрощения архитектуры. А раз если есть такие процессоры, то ради скорости вы выравниваете данные. Почему вы считаете это недостаточным для ответа? Только потому, что слишком просто описано?

Comment: @AlexKrass, да, про свой призыв я уже увидел, извиняюсь, исправил) Касательно ответа «для удешевления и упрощения архитектуры», такими темпами можно любой вопрос на SO свести к «ну, так надо для производительности» или просто «ну, так надо». Лично меня такой ответ не очень устроил бы, хочется узнать, что там реально внутри происходит — вопрос-то про процессорам, тут всегда интересны детали. Кого-то, конечно, может быть и устроил простой ответ, но, судя по вопросам ТС, ему также интересно, что там — под капотом.

Comment: Почему ваши вопросы обходят стороной - для их нормального изложения нужно написать несколько глав из учебника по архитекутре ЭВМ или перевести кусок стандарта C++

Допустим, кто-то попытается коротко на это ответить, но обрежет пару мелких нюансов - и немедленно выхватит минусов от остальной аудитории сайта, потому что для них именно эти нюансы окажутся важными.

Итого, ваши вопросы вызывают желание послать вас в хороший инженерный вуз, это продуктивнее, чем пересказывать вам учебник.

Comment: @eanmos - что там под капотом закопано глубоко под NDA, Таким образом, кто реально знает что там, ограничены NDA. Остается только придумывать вымышленный процессор, а в нем выдумывать проблему, решение которой будет приводит к этим ограничениям. В этом месте ответ "из инженерных и экономических соображений" становится не таким уж плохим.

Comment: @eanmos, обычно разработчику максимально нужно знать эти тонкости примерно на уровне подобной статьи: [IBM: Data alignment: Straighten up and fly right](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/systems/articles/pa-dalign/). Остальное это уже сложности проектирования СБИС (и выше) и тут нужен для ответа проектировщик железа, чтобы ответить, какие трудности повлечет за собой внедрение произвольного доступа со всеми вытекающими. Думаю это реализуемо, но отказываются по объективным причинам. В принципе вы и так уже ответили достаточно и даже больше, в остальном я вас понял)

Comment: @gbg, может для современного железа проблема с NDA и актуальна, но во-первых reverse engineering никто не отменял, и я уверен есть умельцы, кто знает каждый проводок современных плат, а во-вторых срок NDA имеет свойство заканчиваться, так что для каких-нибудь старых процессоров и плат NDA не проблема.

Comment: @gbg, касательно технических вузов. Я не думаю, что в России вообще есть направления микроархитектуры и VLSI: как-то пытался найти магистерскую программу подобной тематики. Да даже если бы и были такие направления сильно сомневаюсь, что там давали материал хоть сколько нибудь близкий к реальным темам. *(продолжение ниже)*

Comment: Я вот, например, сейчас на третьем курсе бакалавриата по направлению «прикладная информатика», так нас на «Архитектуре ЭВМ» учили электромагнитным реле и ПЛК. Я, конечно, понимаю, что на моем направлении нет фокуса на низкоуровневые вещи, но все-таки какое отношение реле и ПЛК имеют к архитектуре ЭВМ в 2021 году? Так что последним пристанищем таких ребят, как ТС и я, остается SO и разные форумы, потому что литературы по подобным темам также не то чтобы очень много.

Comment: @AlexKrass, я совсем не против, чтобы у нас был проектировщик, который мог бы в деталях ответить на подобные вопросы. Все-таки на русском SO немного более широкий онтопик. Да, может быть, прикладному программисту это особо и не нужно, но даже ему для кругозора все-равно полезно это знать, ИМХО.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Дисклеймер**:* *все еще советую вам задать вопрос на английском SO, так как у нас, на сколько я знаю, нет людей которые хорошо разбираются в теме. Я дам ответ, не претендуя на полноту и абсолютную корректность, так как все-таки имею некоторое преставление о рассматриваемом вопросе.*

---

**CPU**

Во-первых, нужно понимать, что нет никаких вселенских запретов на невыровненное чтение. Вполне можно создать CPU, который будет в состоянии читать 3 бита по адресу 17. Проблема в том, что нам нужно, чтобы CPU работал быстро, а в текущих реалиях невыровненный доступ влечет провалы в производительности.

Почему так? Одной из важнейших причин является, то что невыровненное чтение не поддерживается шиной, которая связывает CPU и внешнюю память. Во многих случаях это так называемая [*Front-Side Bus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-side_bus) (FSB). Процессор может выставить любой адрес на свои адресные пины, вот только шина, увидев, что запрашиваемый адрес невыровнен вернет процессору ошибку, а ваш процесс получит сигнал [`SIGBUS`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGBUS).

В реальности запросить у шины данные по невыровненному адресу не так просто. В тех ISA, где невыровненное чтение разрешено, процессор, увидев такой доступ заменит его на два выровненных, а потом «склеит» из считанных кусков запрошенное программистом слово *[[IBM]](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/systems/articles/pa-dalign/)*.

Вот в чем кроется «нелюбовь» процессора к невыровненным чтениям — ему приходится делать дополнительную работу, что очевидно сказывается на производительности.

**Шина**

Теперь другой вопрос — почему шина запрещает такие чтения? Один из возможных ответов заключается в том, что за счет выравнивания шина пытается увеличить адресное пространство. Если мы договорились, что все чтения должны быть выровненны по границе 2<sup>N</sup>, тогда каждый запрашиваемый адрес будет заканчиваться N нулями. В таком случае мы можем не передавать эти N нулей на шину, подразумевая, что они там есть. Тем самым увеличив адресное пространство на N бит <sup>†</sup>.

**Main Memory**

Дальше вспомним, что кроме шины в процессе чтения участвует сама память. Память в большинстве случае реализуется как матрица, состоящая из строк и колонок *[[W1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory#Array_structures)*. Так вот на уровне контроллера памяти чтения и запись происходят не по-байтно, а по-строчно. Обычно размер такой строки — 64 бита (8 байт). Таким образом, запрос чтения от CPU по выровненному адресу будет требовать от контроллера меньше чтений строк. Ведь при невыровненном чтении одна половина запрашиваемого слова может находиться на одной линии матрицы, а вторая половина — на другом. Поэтому контроллеру придется считать обе строки, а потом еще правильно «склеить» из этих кусков нужные данные.

Та же самая логика применяется и к чтению из кэша. Кэш-линия обычно имеет размер в 64 байта *[[SO1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15333156/8086115)*. Чтение по выровненным адресам гарантированно требует доступ только к одной кэш-линии.

Кстати, шина имеет определенную пропускную способность — обычно это также 64 бита. Так как за раз из RAM можно прочитать только 64 бита, то при выровненном доступе мы можем быть уверены, что одного обращения к шине будет достаточно.

Кроме того, запрет на невыровненный доступ имеет и другое преимущество. Представьте, что у вас 128 байт памяти и вы пытаетесь запросить 8 байт по адресу 123. Видите в чем проблема? Запрошенное слово выходит за пределы памяти. Такую ситуацию контроллер тоже должен как-то обрабатывать, что приводит к дополнительной дорогостоящей логике. Запрет на невыровненное чтение решает эту проблему.

---

† <sup>Похожий трюк применяется *[[ARM]](https://iitd-plos.github.io/col718/ref/arm-instructionset.pdf)* в архитектуре ARM, но немного с другой целью. В архитектуре ARM есть два разных набора команд — собственно, ARM и набор коротких команд Thumb. Инструкция `BX`, которая позволяет выполнить условный переход берет адрес перехода из регистра. Трюк в том, что каждая инструкция должна быть выровнена либо по границе в 4 байта, либо по границе в 2 байта. Таким образом наименее значимый бит адреса всегда равен нулю. И инструкция `BX` использует этот нижний бит не в качестве части адреса, а чтобы понять в какой режим перевести процессор — ARM или Thumb.</sup>

‡ <sup>К сожалению, найти материалы по данной теме не так уж и просто. Если со стороны процессора все еще более-менее понятно, то узнать, что происходит в шине и памяти гораздо сложнее. В первую очередь проблема в том, что конкретные детали специфичны для каждого железа. Видимо, детальную информацию, нужно искать в datasheets конкретных плат.</sup>