# почему при записи структуры в файл первое значение всегда занимает 4 байта?

Tags: c

Экспериментирую с BMP изображениями. Прежде чем записывать побайтово значения самой картинки решил записать в двоичном виде для начала заголовок и столкнулся с такой проблемой какой бы тип данных я не выбрал для переменной `init` в структуре `BMP_header` - значения переменной `init` в любом случае записываются 4мя байтами.

Вот структура BMP изображения `global.h`

```
typedef struct {
    short int init;
    int file_size;
    int unusable_values;
    int header_size
} BMP_header;

typedef struct {
    int dib_header_size;
    int width;
    int height;
    short int color_plane
    short int bits_per_pixel;
    int compression;
    int image_contents_size;
    int horisontal_resolution;
    int vertical_resolution;
    int unusable_var1;
    int unusable_var2;
} DIB_header;

typedef struct {
    BMP_header bmp_header;
    DIB_header dib_header;
} BMP;
```

Вот код с помощью которого я записываю файл

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Manipulation/Global/headers/global.h"

void image(int width, int height, int values_array[]);

int main(void) {
    int color = 0x00ffffff;
    int height = 4;
    int width = 4;
    int values_array[width * height];
    for(int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
        values_array[i] = color;
    image(width, height, values_array);
}

void image(int width, int height, int values_array[]) {
    BMP image = {
        0x4d42, 
        (width * height * 4) + 54,
        0x00000000, 
        0x00000036,
        0x00000028, 
        width, 
        height, 
        0x0001, 
        0x0018, 
        0x00000000, 
        width * height * 4, 
        0x00000ec4, 
        0x00000ec4, 
        0x00000000, 
        0x00000000
    };
    BMP *p_image = &image;

    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen("image.bmp", "w")) == NULL) {
        perror("Ошибка создания файла\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    fwrite(p_image, sizeof(image), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Вот что я получаю в итоге

```
42 4D 00 00 76 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00
28 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 18 00
00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 C4 0E 00 00 C4 0E 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

А это то что я ожидал получить

```
42 4D 76 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 28 00
00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 18 00 00 00
00 00 40 00 00 00 C4 0E 00 00 C4 0E 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Вопрос: почему в самом начале после `42 4D` появляются еще 2 байта `00 00`, вне зависимости от типа переменной `init`?

Comment: во всём виновато выравнивание структур до 2^n байт. Причина размера структур 16 байт вместо 14-ти в том, что архитектура памяти компьютера качает память блоками 2^n байт. А если вы сделаете себе структуру в 14 байт, то будет случаи медленного доступа к памяти, так-как будет качаться два блоками вместо одного.

Comment: `какой бы тип данных я не выбрал для переменной init в структуре BMP_header - значения переменной init в любом случае записываются 4мя байтами` Даже если этот тип `long long`? См. [Выравнивание данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435726).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сильно в код не смотрел, но полагаю это происходит из-за выравнивания полей.
Как вариант можно упаковать структуру, чтобы в ней не было "дырок". Как?
В gcc например так:

```
typedef struct
{
    DWORD  biSize; 
    LONG   biWidth; 
    LONG   biHeight; 
    WORD   biPlanes; 
    WORD   biBitCount; 
    DWORD  biCompression; 
    DWORD  biSizeImage; 
    LONG   biXPelsPerMeter; 
    LONG   biYPelsPerMeter; 
    DWORD  biClrUsed; 
    DWORD  biClrImportant; 
} __attribute__((__packed__))
BITMAPINFOHEADER;
```

Еще есть более переносимый вариант pragma pack с ней вы можете ознакомиться самостоятельно.